# Having an edit form and a detail view on the same page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am currently trying to get an edit form working on the same page as a detail view in `Django`.

I am currently trying out the way as recommended on the docs (i.e. using `FormMixin`). So, my view looks like this:

```
class ProductiveMinutesDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = models.ProductiveMinutes
    pk_url_kwarg = 'productiveminutes_pk'
    form_class = forms.EditForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('productiveminutes_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductiveMinutesDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = forms.EditForm(initial={'post': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ProductiveMinutesDetail, self).form_valid(form)
```

And my form looks like this:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ProductiveMinutes
        fields = ('name', 'description',)
```

The model I am using is this:

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProductiveMinutes(models.Model):
    scenario = models.OneToOneField(Scenario)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Using this I can get the form to render on the page but I know I am doing something wrong as the fields are empty when I would like them to be populated with the data that is already present.

Another piece of complexity is that this form should not be editing the `amount` field of the model just the `name` and `description`. The `amount` value is edited separately from the detail view of this page.

So, I guess my main question is how can I get the form to be populated with the data for the models fields that is already present and then edit it. Ideally functionality like that of the generic `UpdateView` that Django provides.

I am using Django version 1.10

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

UPDATE:

My template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'pages/dashboard.html' %}
{% load i18n humanize crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center">Productive Minutes: {{ productiveminutes.name }}</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <h3>Edit productive minutes: {{ productiveminutes.name }}</h3>
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <button class="primaryAction btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">{% trans "Submit" %}</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <h3>Data Records</h3>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead class="thead-default">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Productive Minutes</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ productiveminutes.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ productiveminutes.amount|intcomma }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding `post`; the base view and mixin define that for you.

Comment: As I'm adapting the example from the Django docs they say: `We use FormMixin and implement post() ourselves rather than try to mix DetailView with FormView (which provides a suitable post() already) because both of the views implement get(), and things would get much more confusing.` So, yes I agree it is probably not the best way to be doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) is for displaying detail for an object and having a separate contact form.

In your case, it sound like you want to display the `ProductiveMinutesDetail` object, and have a form that allows you to update some of the fields *of that same object*. In that case, you should just use `UpdateView`.

```
class ProductiveMinutesUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = models.ProductiveMinutes
    pk_url_kwarg = 'productiveminutes_pk'
    form_class = forms.EditForm

    success_url = reverse('productiveminutes_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductiveMinutesUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Refresh the object from the database in case the form validation changed it
        object = self.get_object()
        context['object'] = context['productiveminutes'] = object
        return context
```

Comment: Can I show an `UpdateView` and a `DetailView` on the same page though? I need to be able to show this update form and the value of the amount field on the same page, as can be seen in my current template.

Comment: Not to worry I have it working now, just needed to pass in the template name as well to show the detail I needed as well! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: The update view is built on the same `SingleObjectMixin` as `DetailView`, so you can access the object in the template in the same way. One subtlety that I just remembered is that the form validation will change the object, so it would be a good idea to re-fetch it from the database to avoid confusion when the form is invalid.

Comment: Yeah I will do that. Thanks again for your help